# Kotlin sealed class - how to sort by sealed class similar to sorting by enum

Tags: sorting, kotlin, enums

In Java we can easily sort a Collecion by enum with something like this:

```
Collections.sort(toSortEnumList, new Comparator<theEnum>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(theEnum o1, theEnum o2) {
        return o1.ordinal().compareTo(o2.ordinal());
    }
});
```

and the `toSortEnumList` will be ordered ascending. How can I do this with a Kotlin's sealed classes? I tried sorting by the class names but that's not by enum position. There must be some way to sort by enum position:

```
sealed class GoodCountries {
    
    class Brazil : GoodCountries() {}

    class USA : GoodCountries() {}
    
    class Germany : GoodCountries() {}
    
    class China : GoodCountries() {}
}

 // later on
    
 var toSortList = listOf<GoodCountries>(China(), Brazil(), USA(), Germany())

 Collections.sort(
     toSortList,
     { x: GoodCountries, y: GoodCountries -> y::class.java.name.compareTo(x::class.java.name) }
 )

 Log.v("myTag", toSortList.toString())
```

this prints:

> USA, Germany, China, Brazil

descending order. Not what I want. I want to sort by sealed class order (like ordinal number in Java's enum) like this:

> Brazil, USA, Germany, China

I thought sealed classes are supposed to be better then enums but if I can't do this maybe enums have an advantage.

**UPDATE**: Thanks to Roland's help I was able to find the list of sealed classes. but now I want to sort by it: here is what I have so far:

```
Collections.sort(toSortList, object : Comparator<GoodCountries> {
    override fun compare(left: GoodCountries, right: GoodCountries): Int {
        return Integer.compare(
            GoodCountries::class.sealedSubclasses.indexOf(left), 
            GoodCountries::class.sealedSubclasses.indexOf(right)
        )
    }
})
```

but I get the following error at `indexOf`:

> Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in input types (argument type, receiver type or expected type). Try to specify it explicitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not completely what you are looking for, but maybe it is...

While the sealed classes don't seem to have something like an ordinal, which you've already noticed, there is [`sealedSubclasses`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/sealed-subclasses.html) on the `class` itself (i.e. `GoodCountries::class.sealedSubclasses`). Also, it seems as if the order of the [`sealedSubclasses`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/sealed-subclasses.html) is the one of the defined classes, i.e. `Brazil` in this list always comes first, `USA` second, etc. The order is different if they aren't all nested (i.e. if some are outside, they are listed first).

However: the documentation doesn't state that this ordering was chosen deliberately. Neither in the ['Sealed classes' reference documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) nor in the [`sealedSubclasses` (k)documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/sealed-subclasses.html).

Regarding your question about sorting entities in the sealed class order, you may want to use something like the following:

```
val entityList = listOf(Germany(), China(), USA(), Brazil(), Germany())
entityList.sortedBy { // or use sortedWith(compareBy {
  GoodCountries::class.sealedSubclasses.indexOf(it::class)
}.forEach(::println) // or toList...
```

or something like:

```
GoodCountries::class.sealedSubclasses
    .asSequence()
    .flatMap { klazzInOrder ->
      entityList.asSequence().filter { it::class == klazzInOrder }
    }
    .forEach(::println)
```

Both might not be the best choices regarding performance, but I think you get the idea.

The sort samples which I added before (when I didn't realize that you actually want to sort entities instead of the types):

```
println("Listing the sealed classes in the order of their declaration*")
GoodCountries::class.sealedSubclasses.forEach(::println)

println("Listing the sealed classes ordered by their simple name")
GoodCountries::class.sealedSubclasses.sortedWith(compareBy(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) { it.simpleName!! })
  .forEach(::println)
// same result, but written differently
GoodCountries::class.sealedSubclasses.sortedBy { it.simpleName?.toLowerCase() }
  .forEach(::println)
```

You may even want to combine `nullsLast` and `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` (most probably if you are not dealing with sealed classes) in which case you would write something like:

```
GoodCountries::class.sealedSubclasses.sortedWith(compareBy(nullsLast(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)) { it.simpleName })
  .forEach(::println)
```

Comment: can you show me how to do the sorting. thanks to your help i found the following:  GoodCountries::class.nestedClasses but it gives me the classes in the wrong order

Comment: Which version of Kotlin do you use? Since 1.3 there exists `sealedSubclasses` which you should try instead of `nestedClasses`.. the sample is actually there in the answer: `GoodCountries::class.sealedSubclasses`

Comment: You may need `kotlin-reflect`-dependency... `sealedSubclasses` was also mentioned in the [What's New in Kotlin 1.3](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew13.html#sealed-classes-in-reflection)

Comment: can you help me to sort it now. i have the following but it says it cant infer the type and indexOf is underlined in red:     Collections.sort(toSortList, object : Comparator<GoodCountries> {
            override fun compare(left: GoodCountries, right: GoodCountries): Int {
                return Integer.compare(GoodCountries::class.sealedSubclasses.indexOf(left), GoodCountries::class.sealedSubclasses.indexOf(right))
            }
        })    i updated my question so you can see what i have done so far

Comment: @j2emanue why do you want to sort the `GoodCountries` sealed subclasses? if you access the `sealedSubclasses` the order is the one of their declaration*... but as also stated in the answer, don't know whether that is deliberate... so take that with a grain of salt... I don't understand your sample code... if you just want to sort it in ~string-based order, you may just want to do: `GoodCountries::class.sealedSubclasses.sortedBy { it.simpleName }`... but the way I understood you, you want the order of there declaration... which the answer basically describes ;-)

Answer (score 9):

You could give your `GoodCountries` an `order` property like so:

```
sealed class GoodCountries(val order: Int) {
    class Brazil : GoodCountries(0)
    class USA : GoodCountries(1)
    class Germany : GoodCountries(2)
    class China : GoodCountries(3)
}
```

It's not a perfect solution since you have to enumerate by hand, but this way the desired order is guaranteed.

Doing this would simplify your comparison code dramatically:

```
val sorted = toSortList.sortedBy(GoodCountries::order)
println(sorted.map { it::class.simpleName })
```

Output:

> [Brazil, USA, Germany, China]

**Edit:** Updated with great idea of [Chrispher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5437033/chrispher) which made the code even cleaner (having `order` property in constructor of `GoodCountries` instead of making it an abstract variable which is overriden by the subclasses).

Comment: Or alternatively if you don't like overriding, you can always do something like this: http://gist.github.com/chriscoomber/c351a2075eeff005f1e6bc4c8143b4af (My personal preference is to avoid OOP where it doesn't add any obvious value, as it's usually much more confusing. In my link, we're just using the sealed class like a sealed trait.)

Comment: @Chrispher I can only agree. I updated my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer to your question is to switch `x` and `y` in your comparator, ie `x::class.java.name.compareTo(y::class.java.name)`

The longer answer is, for your use case, an enum might be better. Sealed classes shine when some subclasses look different than others, and it's meaningful to have multiple instances of them. For example a `sealed class Result` with subclasses `Success` and `Error`, where `Success` holds data and `Error` holds an exception. Assuming you want to treat all countries the same, your use case seems like it might be more suited to a traditional enum.

Comment: I want to sort the list by the ORDER of the enum not my ascending order. How can your suggested comparator do that? It's doing lexographic sort. I want enum sorry. Let me know if it's not possible with sealed class

Comment: Oh I see. I'm not sure there's any way to get that order at runtime. Use an enum if that's something you need.